# Query column for any of multiple variations of a substring in SQLite, Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a data table that has one column called Threads.RECEPIENT_IDS.  In that column, I can have rows like: 4,10,25,60 or 2,4,8,20 or just 4.  How would I query all rows that contain a 4 or query for all instances that a row contains a 4 or 20.  I thought of something like:

```
String queryString = "'4','%,4','4,%','%,4,%','20','%,20','20,%','%,20,%'";
```

I just can't figure out why this doesn't return any rows. My parameters and cursorLoader is below.

```
private final String[] threadsProjection = new String[] { Treads.RECIPIENT_IDS };
private final String threadsSelection = Threads.RECIPIENT_IDS + " like ?";
private final String threadsOrder = Threads.DATE + " DESC";

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {

    switch (loaderID) {
    case SMS_MMS_QUERY:
        String queryString = bundle.getString(BUNDLE_QUERY_KEY);
        CursorLoader queryCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, conversationsUri, threadsProjection, threadsSelection, new String[]{queryString}, threadsOrder);
        return queryCursorLoader;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but why that comma? Isn't the correct way '%4%' and not '%,4,%'  ?

Answer (score 2):

This goes back to database design, and using text field to hold a list of IDs is just very poor design. A better design here would be a separate table to hold the IDs, such as --

`TABLE threads( *threadId, <info>, <info> )`

and

`TABLE thread_recipients( *threadId, *recipientId )`

where `*` marks a primary key.

You would then populate both tables with your threads, and the query would be something simple, such as:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM threads 
 WHERE threadId IN ( SELECT threadId 
                       FROM thread_recipients
                      WHERE recipientId = ? )
```

There is no reliable way of doing what you are trying to do with the current schema. Even the `LIKE` queries will fail when you attempt to find recipientId "4" if there's a "24" or "34" etc.